# Form will either validate or redirect, but not both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've searched all over these forums and tried a number of different solutions, but I'm just not able to find a way to make my form validate the First Name, Last Name and Email fields, while redirecting afterward. I can get it to do one or the other, but not both.

Below is my code. I'm new to javascript, but I think I'm close to having this work:

```
    <script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() {
            alert("submitted!");
        }
    });

    $().ready(function() {
        // validate the comment form when it is submitted
        $("#commentForm").validate();

        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },

    });

    $("#signupForm").submit(function(event){
        window.location = 'http://www.lifebridgehealth.org/campaign/newneighborsdownload.aspx';
    });
    </script>

</script>

    <style>
    #commentForm {
        width: 500px;
    }
    #commentForm label {
        width: 250px;
    }
    #commentForm label.error, #commentForm input.submit {
        margin-left: 253px;
    }
    #signupForm {
        width: 670px;
    }
    #signupForm label.error {
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: auto;
        display: inline;
    }
    #newsletter_topics label.error {
        display: none;
        margin-left: 103px;
    }
    </style>



<body>
<div id="main">
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
            <input type="hidden" class="reference" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.RecordTypeId" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.RecordTypeId" value="01246000000tqltAAA" />
    <input type="hidden" class="picklist" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Status__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Status__c" value="Open" />
    <input type="hidden" class="string" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Subject__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__Subject__c" value="DG_LBH_PRIM_NewMovers_CY17 form submission" />
    <input type="hidden" class="picklist" id="Patient.LeadSource" name="Patient.LeadSource" value="Web Form: DG_LBH_Primary Care_New Movers" />
    <input type="hidden" class="picklist" id="Patient.HC4__MostRecentLeadSource__c" name="Patient.HC4__MostRecentLeadSource__c" value="Web Form: DG_LBH_Primary Care_New Movers_FY17" />
    <input type="hidden" class="string" id="DemandConnectForm" name="DemandConnect.Form" value="DG_LBH_PRIM_NewMovers_CY17" />
    <label class="string" id="Patient.FirstName_label" for="Patient.FirstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="string" id="Patient.FirstName" name="Patient.FirstName" value="" required/><br/>
    <label class="string" id="Patient.LastName_label" for="Patient.LastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="string" id="Patient.LastName" name="Patient.LastName" value="" required/><br/>
    <label class="email" id="Patient.Email_label" for="Patient.Email">Email</label><input type="text" class="email" id="Patient.Email" name="Patient.Email" value="" required/><br/>
    <label class="string" id="Patient.PostalCode_label" for="Patient.PostalCode">Mailing Zip/Postal Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="string" id="Patient.PostalCode" name="Patient.PostalCode" value="" /><br/>
    <label class="phone" id="Patient.Phone_label" for="Patient.Phone">Home Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="phone" id="Patient.Phone" name="Patient.Phone" value="" data-fv-field="phonenumber"/><br/>
    <label class="phone" id="Patient.MobilePhone_label" for="Patient.MobilePhone">Mobile Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="phone" id="Patient.MobilePhone" name="Patient.MobilePhone" value="" data-fv-field="phonenumber"/><br/>
    <label class="picklist" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__PreferredContactMethod__c_label" for="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__PreferredContactMethod__c">Preferred Contact Method</label>
    <select type="picklist" class="picklist" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__PreferredContactMethod__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.HC4__PreferredContactMethod__c" />
    <option value="Home Phone">Home Phone</option>
    <option value="Mobile Phone">Mobile Phone</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <label class="picklist" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.Best_Time_to_Reach_You__c_label" for="HC4__Inquiry__c.Best_Time_to_Reach_You__c">Best Time to Reach You</label>
    <select type="picklist" class="picklist" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.Best_Time_to_Reach_You__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.Best_Time_to_Reach_You__c" />
    <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
    <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
    <option value="Evening">Evening</option> 
    </select>
    <br/>
        <label class="boolean" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.Call_Me_Back_to_Schedule_an_Appointment__c_label" for="HC4__Inquiry__c.Call_Me_Back_to_Schedule_an_Appointment__c">Please Call Me Back to Schedule an Appointment</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="boolean" id="HC4__Inquiry__c.Call_Me_Back_to_Schedule_an_Appointment__c" name="HC4__Inquiry__c.Call_Me_Back_to_Schedule_an_Appointment__c" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <br/>

    <label class="boolean" id="Patient.WantstoLearnMoreAboutLBH__c_label" for="Patient.WantstoLearnMoreAboutLBH__c" >Learn More About LBH?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="boolean" id="Patient.WantstoLearnMoreAboutLBH__c" name="Patient.WantstoLearnMoreAboutLBH__c" checked />
    <br/>
            </p>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
$("#DG_LBH_PRIM_NewMovers_CY17").validate();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be performing your validation within your submit function `$("#signupForm").submit(...`

The submit function then normally needs to return either true or false. True will trigger the form submission, false will prevent the submission.

As you want to redirect elsewhere, you are better off overriding the default functionality entirely. Do this by calling preventDefault on the submit event.

`$("#signupForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()...`

Then you can perform your validation and redirect if necessary

Comment: I've changed it to the below, but it's not working still

$("#signupForm").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
 
 $.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
   alert("submitted!");
  }
 });

 $().ready(function() {
  // validate the comment form when it is submitted
  $("#commentForm").validate();

  // validate signup form on keyup and submit
  $("#signupForm").validate({
   rules: {
    firstname: "required",
    lastname: "required",
    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true
    },
  
 });
 window.location = 'http...';
 
    });